# PHP Bz2 extension question

Tags: php, bzip2

When I am using [`bzopen`](http://php.net/bzopen), do I need to `bzwrite()` already compressed by a `bzcompress()` string or is it being compressed automatically while writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by **Example #1** on the manual page of **[`bzwrite`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.bzwrite.php)** *(quoting)* :

```
<?php
$str = "uncompressed data";
$bz = bzopen("/tmp/foo.bz2", "w");
bzwrite($bz, $str, strlen($str));
bzclose($bz);
?>
```

I would say there is no need to compress data yourself with `bzcompress` before using `bzwrite`.

Also, executing this portion of code will create a file with content that looks like this :

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.bz2
BZh91AY&SY7�w�@.� 1�&2��� q�o
|]��B@���`
```

Doesn't look like "`uncompressed data`" -- and looks like some bzip2-compressed data ;-)

Comment: I saw this example, but if it's so where can you choose compress level? and why does it needs to be external bzcompress() function?

Comment: the external `bzcompress()` function exists so you can compress data without sending it to a file *(you might want to send it to the browser, for instance, or store it in a database)* ;;; no idea about how to set the compression level -- sorry.